# Detecting line breaks within Python/Django textarea fields

Tags: python, django

I have a textarea field in Django from which I want to detect line breaks. I can see that the line breaks are stored as reloading the page with the user input shows the breaks that the user inputted, but I can't detect them in Django/Python.

When I look at the output from PostgreSQL I can see \r characters, but these don't seem to show up within the Python environment.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
text_blocks = text_area.split("\r")
```

But this doesn't work and I suspect is naive.

How can I detect these seemingly invisible line breaks within Python/Django?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "detect"? What do you want to do with the information?

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for your consideration on this. I've found an error in my code now, all seems far less mysterious. Incidentally I want to separate the paragraphs into a list to help me write them into an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `splitlines()`, this is a built-in string method of python:

```py
text_blocks = text_area.splitlines()
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

> Return a list of the lines in the string, breaking at line boundaries.
>   Line breaks are not included in the resulting list unless keepends is
>   given and true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this also doesn’t detect the line breaks within the textarea. Using it results in the full text contained within the first element of the list.

Comment: strange, it  works for my scenario. we have variable length options for a question, and enter used for the new option. I split the string using this method. works perfectly for me

Comment: Nalin - thanks for your answer, I've found an error in my code that was responsible for my problem. Your approach works well now. I'll mark it as correct, I'm sure it'll help someone else.